# Excel VBA code works in Personal Macro Workbook but not as ActiveX button

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I have a macro stored in my PERSONAL.xlsb that works.  I'm trying to enable the same macro using an ActiveX button instead, in a macro-enabled excel template, so that I can more easily share updates to the macro with other users.  I copied the code to the new macro-enabled template so that it will be activated when the ActiveX command button is pressed, but the code doesn't seem to run without stopping for debugging every few lines.  Are there different requirements for how to code for ActiveX compared to how to code for PERSONAL.xlsb?

Comment: There isn't a different spec for ActiveX controls, they just have different properties/methods - but in general you should always use form controls unless you specifically need an ActiveX control. You will need to post your code for further assistance

Comment: What's the code? What errors are you getting? What S O Said.

Comment: If I read correctly, the error is "stopping for debugging every few line". In other words, it's dropping back to the VBE either due to a real breakpoint, or an false one.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions.  I took the advice of S O and embedded the code in a form control button instead, and the code executed without any issues.  Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Some of these fixes may (or may not) work. But they will address common halting issues.

Try going to the VB-Editor, Debug Menu, and selecting clear all breakpoints. Halting sometime is also caused by have set watches and the not clearing them, so go to view, watches and make sure your don't have any set.

Failing that, try selecting all, cut to the clipboard (ctrl-x), do Debug>Compile, paste the code back in and compile again. Sometimes the underlying pcode gets into a weird state and this will cause it to be re-written.

At long last, if none of this works, you may need to export your code modules, import them into new workbook, and replace your personal workbook.